# Cast String to Int64 causes crash on 32bit devices

Tags: ios, swift, 32-bit, int64

I have to deal with a pretty long Int, that comes to me as a String. Calling 
`Int64(String)` works fine on 64bit devices, but I see crashes on 32bit devices. What is the reason for this?

Here is the code:

```
let predicateBarcode = NSPredicate(format: "barcode = %ld", Int64(searchTerm)!)
```

I cannot tell anything about the searchterm, it comes from the barcode scanner and is an ean-13. I can also not reproduce the crash, as this is only happening to my costomers.

Comment: `Int64` represents 64-bit signed integer for both 32-bit and 64-bit platforms. So, usually we cannot see such behaviors. Can you show more context to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Please show your code and details of the crash.

Comment: Is that really the exact code you are using? Your code does not compile with Xcode 8.3. Please do not omit anything, even if you think is irrelevant. And show the value of  `searchTerm` when crashing. Anyway your code is not a valid code even in 64-bit platform.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not the problem of `Int64.init(_:)` but the problem of the format given to `NSPredicate`.

Length specifier `l` means its argument needs to be `long` or `unsigned long`, which are equivalent to `Int` or `UInt` in Swift.

[String Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html)

If you want to use `Int64` value as a format argument, the right length specifier is `ll`, meaning `long long` which is equivalent to `Int64` in Swift.

```
let predicateBarcode = NSPredicate(format: "barcode = %lld", Int64(searchTerm)!)
```

You may need to fix some other parts, but I cannot see as you are hiding other parts. (And as far as I test, I could not make my testing app crash.) In addition, are you 100%-sure about `Int64(searchTerm)!` may not crash?

Anyway, the format string needs to be fixed at least.

Comment: Thanks, I will fix this. I additionally changed the code to verify ithat Int64(searchTerm) is not nil.

Comment: Hope your code has no other faults or you can find them soon if any. Good luck.